# cannot find whats causing Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I can't find what causing this error in my database, I posted some question before related to this issue but since the code is quite long i remove some of them that has the same 
declaration because stackoverflow won't allow me to post more than 3000 characters. i tried using this method to close the cursor, but somehow it doesn't fix the problem.

```
public Cursor getMove(){
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID1, KEY_MOVENAME};

    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    } finally {
        if(c != null){
            c.close();
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Anyway [[here's]](http://www.mediafire.com/view/?qusyl19lc2c1ak4) the whole class I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What error are you encountering?

Comment: Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed

Comment: Hm, yeah it seems like it should be fine if you call close in finally blocks every time. If you post your entire code in a gist or pastebin  instead of mediafire it would be easier to read. There are some syntax errors in it so I think something is lost in translation.

Comment: sorry about that, but i think i found out the source of the error, but now another error appear, hahah... one of my method returns a cursor the problem is that i closed it before it even returns anything, so i remove the close and it did fixed the issue but another one appear, still working on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the cursor is the reason why I'm getting this error so instead of this:

```
public Cursor getMove(){
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID1, KEY_MOVENAME};

    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    } finally {
        if(c != null){
            c.close();
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

I just used this line of code:

```
public Cursor getMove(){
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID1, KEY_MOVENAME};

    Cursor c = null;
    c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be that you are using multiple instances of your DB connections and not closing all cursors that you hand out. The answer that you accepted (your own) could be dangerous. Are you releasing the cursors that you hand out from this method ? You will end up taking precious resources on the phone that will never be released if you don't.

You can solve this by maintaining one database instance (by using a singleton to handle the DB connections) and closing all cursors eventually. Either marshal them into POJOs and close the cursors immediately or send back a cursor and manage it with a call to a method like `activity.managedQuery()`. You might also want to look at android's [SQL lite locking](http://kagii.com/post/6828016869/android-sqlite-locking) mechanism.